# TemplateSyntaxError using with filter() in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm getting this issue web ussing filter on the template to display a button when a condition occurs

My view:

```
def grupos(request):
modalidades = Modalidad.objects.filter(disciplina=1).filter(temporada__activo__exact=True).order_by('-siglas')

context = {'modalidades': modalidades}
return render(request, 'temporadas/grupos.html', context=context)
```

My models:

```
class Modalidad(models.Model):
    disciplina = models.ForeignKey(Disciplina, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Categoría')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categoria_insc = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria, related_name='categoria_insc')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.siglas


class Grupos(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    siglas = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'G{str(self.siglas)}'


class Team(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    temporada = models.ForeignKey(Temporada, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    modalidad = models.ForeignKey(Modalidad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    siglas = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grupo = models.ForeignKey(Grupos, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='grupos')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

And finally my template:

```
{% for m in modalidades %}
      <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-xxl-1 text-center pb-4 pb-xxl-0 ">
          <span class="fs-3 lh-1">{{ m.siglas }}</span>
          <h1 class="fs-3 pt-3">{{ m.team_set.all|length }}</h1>
     {% if m.team_set.filter(grupo__isnull=True) %}
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm me-1 mb-1" type="button">Crear Grupos</button>
     {% endif %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm getting the error: Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Could not parse the remainder: '(grupo__isnull=True)' from 'm.team_set.filter(grupo__isnull=True)'

can I do this kind of things in the template? or how to use the filter method in the tempalte correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform ORM operations like `Model.objects.filter` directly in templates, owing to the separation of template HTML from manipulated code.

Generally, it's good practice to do this in your view, if possible. This makes life simpler as all the information for the template is provided by context.  You can use [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) to output the boolean value of your team_set query to an annotation field. So something like this might work:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
...
modalidades = (Modalidad.objects.
    .filter(disciplina=1)
    .filter(temporada__activo__exact=True)
    .annotate(
         grupo_isnull=ExpressionWrapper(
               Q(team_set__grupo__isnull=True),
               output_field=BooleanField()
         )
    )
    .order_by('-siglas')
)
```

Then your template can simply ask

```
{% if m.grupo_isnull %}
```